# react-native -bash: react-native: command not found

Tags: react-native

I Install node and Watchman

```
 brew install node
 brew install watchman
```

then Install React Native CLI

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

but when I use react-native init test

I have error:
-bash: react-native: command not found

Answer (score 1):

try: `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli`

or **npx**  before react native as: `npx react-native init demo`

Answer (score 0):

first
       `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli`

this command output path like this

`/usr/local/bin/react-native -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js`

then(for above path example)

`export PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js"`

`react-native init appName`

Comment: I do all this but again -bash: react-native: command not found